# Get notified when object in third party S3 bucket gets updated

Tags: amazon-web-services, events, amazon-s3

I need to monitor a file on a third party public s3 bucket and would like to get notified when the file gets updated(replaced). Please note that the third party is not going to implement a Lambda trigger for me so S3 Lambda event triggers etc won't help. Any solution other than polling?

Like i said the bucket is a third party bucket who is unlikely to make any modifications on their part to deliver created object events to a lambda or queue.

Comment: I assume that by third party you mean someone that has a public s3 bucket. Is it a particular file that you want to monitor?

Comment: Yes we want to monitor a specific file hosted by someone in a public S3 bucket and take actions every time it is updated

Comment: It look like you have to create your own solution. Like check metadata by cron.

Answer (score 2):

If the bucket owner is unwilling to do anything (eg configure Amazon S3 Events), then there is **no way to be automatically notified** when an object is added/updated.

This is good — would you want other people to be able to monitor *your* buckets like that? Presumably not.

If the bucket is publicly accessible, you should be able to call `HeadObject()` on the file at regular intervals to determine whether it has changed. The Create Date and eTag should be sufficient to detect a change.